# How to perform Modulo of boost::cpp_dec_float_50 and boost::int1024_t Data Types?

Tags: c++, boost, modulo, boost-multiprecision

I'm trying to perform a modulo operation on two numbers. One is a `cpp_dec_float_50` type (decimal) number, and the other is a `int1024_t` type number - both supplied by the Boost Multiprecision C++ library.

I've tried using the `%` operator, and the Standard Library's `fmod()` function, but alas they aren't designed for such data types. I've scoured the Boost documentation however there is no trace of a modulous alternative that would work with its own floating point data types.

Please note that the `int1024_t` value is *very* large.

There must be SOME way to perform a modulo operation on such values, hopefully someone can shed some light on it for me.

Cheers.

Comment: You can't use the modulo operator on floating point numbers.

Comment: @user14717 I'm aware, that's why I tried the fmod() operation.

Comment: Do you know that your floating point value in an integer? If so cast it to `int1024_t`.

Comment: @user14717 how do you mean? My floating point value may be 0.2, for instance. I don't think I can cast that to int1024_t.

Comment: If it's 0.2, then how do you define the modulo operation?

Comment: @user14717 Well it would be fmod(0.2, 205757961451002850) for instance, but the second number is too big for primitive types.

Comment: I'm asking "what do you think 0.2 % 205757961451002850 to means?"

Comment: Obviously what is the remainder after dividing those two numbers.

Comment: Why not define it as a free function yourself? It's just a division, truncate to an integer then a subtraction?

Comment: "Obviously what is the remainder after dividing those two numbers." There is no remainder.